# How to Edit Save Word File to a Database and display in a Frame

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a Computer Based Examination Software, and having problem saving maths Equations, Tables and other formatted Questions to database. examples in Images[image] [image] [image] [image]

I have sorted out a solution by converting Word Files to image (through other software) and uploading to database and displaying in the explorer-Frame.

But the conversion from a Word File to Image is bit difficult for an end user.

**> Can some one help me out a simple and easy method for same.**

The application I am working on, is Asp.Net(web based) basis and I am using SQL Server 2005.

Regards,

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by saving a Word document as an image? What does that have to do with an asp.net page? Can you just store the html in your database that generates the question? A lot more detail is needed here to offer much of a solution.

Comment: I am converting the word file to a image, by means of custom software, and upload that Image to Database as question.